# Python PIL: How to draw an ellipse in the middle of an image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ellipse

I seem to be having some trouble getting this code to work:

```
import Image, ImageDraw

im = Image.open("1.jpg")

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.ellipse((60, 60, 40, 40), fill=128)
del draw 

im.save('output.png')
im.show()
```

This should draw an ellipse at (60,60) which is 40 by 40 pixels. The image returns nothing.

This code works fine however:

```
draw.ellipse ((0,0,40,40), fill=128)
```

It just seems that when i change the first 2 co-ords (for where the ellipse should be placed) it won't work if they are larger than the size of the ellipse to be drawn. For example:

```
draw.ellipse ((5,5,15,15), fill=128)
```

Works, but only shows part of the rect. Whereas

```
draw.ellipse ((5,5,3,3), fill=128)
```

shows nothing at all.

This happens when drawing a rectangle too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The bounding box is a 4-tuple `(x0, y0, x1, y1)` where `(x0, y0)` is the top-left bound of the box and `(x1, y1)` is the lower-right bound of the box.

To draw an ellipse to the center of the image, you need to define how large you want your ellipse's bounding box to be (variables `eX` and `eY` in my code snippet below).

With that said, below is a code snippet that draws an ellipse to the center of an image:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

im = Image.open("1.jpg")

x, y =  im.size
eX, eY = 30, 60 #Size of Bounding Box for ellipse

bbox =  (x/2 - eX/2, y/2 - eY/2, x/2 + eX/2, y/2 + eY/2)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.ellipse(bbox, fill=128)
del draw

im.save("output.png")
im.show()
```

This yields the following result (`1.jpg` on left, `output.png` on right):

[image: 1.jpg] [image: output.png]

Comment: Thanks - the idea of bounding boxes was new to me so i was a bit confused here. Thanks for the great explanation and example :)

Answer (score 3):

The ellipse function draws an ellipse within a **bounding box**.  So you need to use `draw.ellipse((40,40,60,60))` or other coordinates where the top left is smaller than the bottom right.